# How to return a promise value to a computed function/binding within a dom-repeat?

Tags: javascript, polymer, ecmascript-6

I have the following code. Basically what I am doing is iterating over a list of ID's with a dom-repeat. The dom-repeat contains a computed binding that runs for each iteration. I am trying to return something via promises within that binding/function but I can't figure out how to do this. I tried promises/async/await but that won't work I guess.

```
<template id='messagelist' is='dom-repeat' items=[[messages]]>
    [[getUserImage(item.toUserId)]]
</template>


getUserImage: function(toUserId) {

  const callWithPromise = (method, myParameters) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Meteor.call(method, myParameters, (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject('Something went wrong');
        resolve(res);
      });
    });
  }

  async function getFacebookUserId() {
    const facebookUserId = await callWithPromise('getUserImage', toUserId);
    return facebookUserId;
  }

  // returns a promise, how do I get the value so I can return it to the getUserImage function?
  console.log(getFacebookUserId());
  return getFacebookUserId();

}



      },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qrxbds99/

Comment: FYI: `async`/`await` aren't part of ES6. Both `console.log` and the subsequent `return` statement only work with synchronous control flows. But you deal with non-blocking functions and a future value wrapped in a `Promise` here and these "asynchronous things" just doesn't disappear magically. I don't know how `async`/`await` works, but usually you would return a `Promise`. Since `facebookUserId` is a Promise you probably should return that. If you need to apply another function to that Promise or its wrapped value, invoke its `then` method: `facebookUserId.then(x => ...)